# axios post request as query to neo4j graph DB

Tags: reactjs, neo4j, react-redux, axios

How to pass parameter to query in react axios ? Here is sample code which i did but no luck. Please advise.

note : API from Neo4j graph db

```
    onSearchSubmit(term){
        console.log(term);
   axios({
       method:'post',
       url:'http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher',
       data:{
           query:'MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) where n.nme=$term RETURN n,r,m',
       }
   }).then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
   }) ;
    }
```

Comment: Did you check your browser network tab to see if its sending data?

Comment: Yes. Error : {message: "Expected parameter(s): term", exception: "ParameterNotFoundException",…}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should use the [neo4j HTTP API](https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/3.5/actions/) (the [neo4j REST API](https://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/) is now deprecated).

Here is an example of how to use the HTTP API to make a single Cypher request with a parameter:

```
onSearchSubmit(term){
  console.log(term);
  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit',
    data: {
      'statements' : [{
        'statement' : 'MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) WHERE n.nme=$term RETURN n,r,m',
        'parameters' : {
          'term' : 'Joe Smith'
        }
      }]
    }
  }).then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Axios signature for post is

`axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`

`data` is the request body. Query params are passed in third argument as follows:

```
.post(`http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher`, null, { params: {
  name: 'Vishal'
}})
.then(response => console.log(response))
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

This will POST an empty body with 1 query params:

POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher?name=Vishal

Comment: Thanks, but how to include query {query:'MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) where n.nme=$term RETURN n,r,m'} becuase i have to pull the data through query only.

Comment: You should execute the query before making the request and inside the params where I wrote name: 'Vishal', you can set name/query to a variable that holds result of your query executed above. like name: nameVariable. Here nameVariable holds some value.

Comment: No , API is from neo4j graph DB and it would respond back with json.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the parameter `term` in the data part.

Parameters can be added to data with key `params` as shown:

```
onSearchSubmit(term) {
    console.log(term);
    axios({
        method:'post',
        url:'http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher',
        data:{
            'query': 'MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) where n.nme=$term RETURN n,r,m',
            'params': {
                'term': 'Insert Term Here'
            }
        }
    }).then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```